# The Type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'

Tags: c#, database, linq

I'm new to C# and i'm learning LINQ now and trying to select some data . . .

```
var carMake = (from table in entity.Make select new { table.ID, table.Name }).ToList();
```

I wrote the above query but i have an error:

```
The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'.
```

I searched the web, but couldn't find any solution. I don't know what's wrong with that query.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: to learn about linq read http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: I think you're looking for this in your select:  `select new { ID = table.ID, Name = table.Name }`.

Comment: @Tim aren't `select new { table.ID, table.Name }` is perfectly legal code if `ID` and `Name` are properties?

Comment: @Tim Anonymous types can be instantiated without specifying the name of the property if a property or field is being selected.  Is this example different for some reason?

Comment: What type is `entity.Make`?

Comment: @BenReich - I was not aware of that.  Thanks.

Comment: Is this Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL (if that even matters)? Also, please post the definitions of `ID` and `Name`. Are they properties?

Comment: @gunr2171 yes Name and Id are properties

Comment: @Jilberta: Is this Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL (if that even matters)? Also, please post the definitions of `ID` and `Name`. (Because you missed my actual questions before).

Answer (score 3):

This code should be fine as long as `entity.Make` is a property of type `IEnumerable<Table>` for some type `Table` with properties `ID` and `Name`.  Please make sure that `Make` has a compatible type for Linq to work with.

It seems possible that some of `Make`, `ID`, or `Name` are methods instead of properties, and you must invoke them (using `Make()`, `ID()`, or `Name()`) where appropriate.  Of course, if `ID` or `Name` are the culprits, then your syntax for instantiating the anonymous type will become invalid, since you cannot declare `new { table.Name() }`.  Instead, you'll have to do `new { Name = table.Name() }`.  Read more about anonymous type instantiating [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

In your example it is unlikely, but I have had the issue before where one of the anonymously typed objects you are trying to create in your select cause are of a type that you do not have referenced.  For example if Name were an XElement, and you did not have a reference to System.Xml.Linq, you would receive this error.

Comment: If this is the case you should also see another error telling you what using you are missing (which I missed before coming here).